# Concatenate cells but check values before - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So I want to concatenate the values from the `D column` to the ones in the `J column`, so far so good, but I want to check if the value from `column D` is already in the `J column`, I used `InStr` and it works until it meets a cell that already has the value that doesn't need to be concatenated

Script:

```
    Sub Concatenate()
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim myValue As Variant
    myValue = InputBox("For how many rows do you want to concatenate D w/ Js")
    d = 4 ' Concatenate from this column
    j = 10 'Concatenate to this column
    ' counter -> Counter to iterate through all the cells in both columns
    For counter = 2 To myValue
      If Cells(counter, d).Value <> "" Then
        If InStr(1, Cells(counter, j).Value, Cells(counter, d).Value) = 0 Then
          Cells(counter, j).Value = Cells(counter, j).Value & "," & Cells(counter, d).Value
        Else
          ' Had to leave it blank
        End If
      End If

    Next counter

End Sub
```

Example

```
How it looks                         How it should look
|    D    |   J     |                 |    D     |      J      |
|    a    |   1     |result of code =>|    a     |     1,a     |
|    b    |   2,b   |result of code =>|    b     |     2,b     | <= (nothing modified)
|    c    |   3     |result of code =>|    c     |     3,c     |
|   abc   |   42    |result of code =>|   abc    |     42,abc  |
```

When meeting the row with the values `|    b    |    2,b    |` the program stops and the rest remain unmodified

Comment: Uhhh...what you want to do when the value from `column D` is in `J Column`? Your code looks good. Right now, your code, if D is in J, then it does nothing. You want to do something different? Add it after your `Else`

Comment: It just has to skip to the next cell, but I couldn't figure it out, and by means of basic programming increasing the counter doesn't seem like a good ideea

Comment: You are using a `For...Next`, so your counter will be increased automatically in every loop. Your code, when D is in J, does nothing, but goes to end of loop, increases counter and repeat the loop again. The only thing weird I see is that line `Next counter` should be `Next contor`. That's all I see. Your code does not work or what?

Comment: So silly, I added counter instead of contor so everyone would understand it, and no, it does not work when everything is written correctly

Comment: How many rows are there?

Comment: Well, 5000, but it doesn't have to run on all of them only on the N rows(input given by user when asked), because only the first 100 could have values in them, or the first 30(it varies)

Comment: Okay, then using the `Integer` datatype shouldn't be a problem. It can hold values untill 32767. Anything larger and your `Integer` will fail. Therefore its almos always better to use `Long`.

Comment: *... it does not work when everything is written correctly...* What do you mean? What you want to do? I still don't see what you want to do when D is in J

Comment: Let's say it has to execute for 15 rows, first 5 have D in J, next 5 don't have D in J, and the last 5 have D in J
This must execute for every row and see if it has the value or not, if it has the value->skip to next row and check again, doesn't have the value-> add the value to J

Comment: Your code does what it _seems_ to me you want. Maybe you want do something different ... Add some examples of a before and after scenarios

Comment: Edited now.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final code, working:

```
Sub Concatenate()
Dim counter As Integer
Dim myValue As Variant
myValue = InputBox("For how many rows do you want to concatenate D w/ Js")
d = 4 ' Concatenate from this column
j = 10 'Concatenate to this column
' counter -> Counter to iterate through all the cells in both columns
For counter = 2 To myValue
  If Cells(counter, d).Value <> "" Then
    If InStr(1, Cells(counter, j).Value, Cells(counter, d).Value) = 0 Then
      Cells(counter, j).Value = Cells(counter, j).Value & "," & Cells(counter, d).Value
    Else
      ' Blank
    End If
  End If
Next counter

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

theres a typo

in the for you have the variable **contor**

```
For contor = 2 To myValue
```

but then you are incrementing then variable **counter**

```
Next counter
```

change the **counter** to **contor** and it should work

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after looking at the ouput you have posted:

```
How it looks                         How it should look
|    D    |   J     |                 |    D     |      J      |
|    a    |   1     |result of code =>|    a     |     1,a     |
|    b    |   2,b   |result of code =>|    b     |     2,b     | <= (nothing modified)
|    c    |   3     |result of code =>|    c     |     3,c     |
|   abc   |   42    |result of code =>|   abc    |     42,abc  |
```

This code should work. Image of data **before applying macro**:

[image]

And after applying macro, I get:

[image]

My code:

```
Sub Concatenate()

Dim Counter As Long
Dim myValue As Variant
myValue = InputBox("For how many rows do you want to concatenate D w/ Js")

For Counter = 2 To myValue Step 1
    If Right(Range("J" & Counter).Value, Len(Range("D" & Counter).Value)) <> Range("D" & Counter).Value Then Range("J" & Counter).Value = Range("J" & Counter).Value & "," & Range("D" & Counter).Value
Next Counter

End Sub
```